# Change Number to it's worded equivalent

Tags: shopify, liquid

This is probably a very quick one, I'm still learning Shopify and Liquid.

Basically, on an invoice I want to display the quantities of products as the word format.

So for example **2** would become **Two**, **10** would become **Ten**.

Is there a function or filter in Shopify that enabled you to do that, or am I looking at writing some complex method to achieve this?

The reason is to make it easier for our fulfilment centre operatives to not miss the quantities peoples orders. We've noticed in a busy period during COVID a lot of mistakes are being made costing the business more money. We hope by doing this makes it easier for them to spot the quantities.

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 0):

There is no such filter.

The only solution is to create a huge string with all the names like so and target them with the number:

```
{% assign names = 'Zero,One,Two' | split: ',' %}
{{ names[2] }}
```